# Prawn. Styling cell object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

How I can build Box with background color and custom text inside with latest version of Prawn ?

In previous prawn version we had

http://rubydoc.info/gems/prawn-layout/0.8.4/Prawn/Table/Cell

with :align, :text_color attributes. So it was easy to build table cell with background color, text align center and custom text color.

After update to latest version from github * prawn (0.11.1.pre 8ed4c22) Table::Cell object changed completely

http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.10.2/Prawn/Table/Cell.html
https://github.com/sandal/prawn/blob/master/lib/prawn/table/cell.rb

Environment

```
rails: 3.0.5
ruby: 1.9.2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ask same question on Prawn mailing list

http://groups.google.com/group/prawn-ruby/browse_thread/thread/7147d92ec6481947

And it was super easy to do it

```
  pdf.bounding_box(pdf.bounds.top_left, :width => x, :height => y) do
    pdf.cell :content => 'your text', :background_color => 'E8E8D0', :width => x, :height => y, :align => :center, :text_color => "001B76"
    pdf.move_down 4
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [`Prawn::Table::Cell::Text`](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.10.2/Prawn/Table/Cell/Text.html), that has `text_color` and `background_color` (inherited from `Prawn::Table::Cell`) methods. You might have to do the horizontal alignment by hand but you could make your own subclass of `Prawn::Table::Cell::Text` or `Prawn::Table::Cell` to hide the ugly details.